# How to call a leaflet Javascript Function in dropdown menu bar?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, html, css

I am having the following problem:

My target is a hybrid application with leaflet. I create a drop down menu with

html/CSS/JQuery. 
Here is the code:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li id="menuPoint1"><image src="../img/Icon/info.png"/>
        <ul class="subMenuPoint1">
            <li class="firstLi"><a href='#'>Interpretation</a></li>
            <li ><a href='#'>Kennblatt</a></li>
            <hr>
            <image src="http://maps.ioer.de/cgi-bin/wms?MAP=S02RG_1000&&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&FORMAT=image/jpeg&LAYER=S02RG_2012_a"/>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menuPoint2"><image src="../img/Icon/ebenen.png"/></li>
    <li id="menuPoint3"><image src="../img/Icon/kalender.png"/></li>
    <li id="menuPoint4"><image src="../img/Icon/lupe.png"/>
        <ul class="subMenuPoint4">
            <li id="search"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menuPoint5"><image src="../img/Icon/helligkeit.png"/></li>
</ul>
```

Now I like to call the Leaflet Geosearch Plug in from https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch at the point li id="search"

I know how to call the function within the JavaScript part, but not within the list element, which is outside the Leaflet function.

The code for the Leaflet Map is:

```
new L.Control.GeoSearch({
        position: 'topcenter',
        provider: new L.GeoSearch.Provider.OpenStreetMap(),
    }).addTo(map);
```

Which I like to implement in the drop down menu.

Comment: Does the search option support changes in its visibility?  If you leave it as a global you could toggle the visibility with the list item.  Or you put the JS event listener in the leaflet code after the list item is created (so it is there and doesn't throw a undefined exception).  Have you tried any of this?  Outline what you may have tried in an **edit** to your question.

Comment: I think it is not possible, because this small snippet based on the following function: https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch/blob/master/src/js/l.control.geosearch.js which used a DOM Element of the Leaflet lib

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution :

```
var search = document.getElementById('suche');

    search.appendChild(new L.Control.GeoSearch({
                      provider: new L.GeoSearch.Provider.OpenStreetMap(),
                }).onAdd(map));
```